# QGIS Shortest Route Network Analysis using multiple features

Tags: qgis, routing, network

Below are the steps to find the shortest route between two points in a road network https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/network_analysis.html

Is it possible to find the shortest route using the road network, but from a point feature where the point doesn't sit on a road, to the nearest road and follow the shortest route to a point on another feature? So three features, initial start point, road and end point.

If so, can this be done for multiple routes that all end up at the same end point? So the start point feature will have many points, and follow the shortest routes to one endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible in QGIS 3.0. The processing toolbox in 3.0 has told for running shortest path analysis based on various combinations of source and destination point layers.