# Calculation of fastest path with in network analysis by qgis 3.0

Tags: select-by-attribute, qgis-3, shortest-path, network-analysis

I have a road network (with speed limit) and different points connected to the roads. I would like to measure the distance between several points along the roads. Basically I want to do **shortest path and fastest path** analysis, but I want to measure the **distance and time** between two points and also would like to get the **results in an attribute table**.

Comment: i am using QGIS 3.0

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck and what is your question? Take the tour: https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259320/qgis-shortest-route-network-analysis-using-multiple-features See also: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=qgis+shortest+path+analysis

Comment: i am doing network analysis in QGIS 3.0 ...i calculated the shortest path using point to layer option  .....i got output in form of map but i am not getting result (Length and time) in attribute table. how to update attribute table (mainly Time and length)