# Shortest route batch calculation in QGIS 3.2.2 with v.net.path GRASS GUI

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-network-analysis

[image]

I have three shapefiles: road network, postcodes and destinations. I`d like to calculate the shortest route between the postcodes and destinations (multiple points in each layer)

Could anyone describe the batch process for this? I have tried the v.net.path but it does not allow batch process (There is no way I can import a CSV file or add a layer).

I am working in QGIS 3.2.2

I do not think that this is a duplicate of [QGIS Shortest Route Network Analysis using multiple features](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259320/qgis-shortest-route-network-analysis-using-multiple-features) because that question is pretty outdated. The tutorial is for QGIS 2.18, I`m using QGIS 3.2.2. Also, I`m asking about batch process, therefore it`s not a duplicate.

Comment: Did you try the solution suggested here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259320/qgis-shortest-route-network-analysis-using-multiple-features

Comment: Do you need to retrieve the actual geometry of the shortest path or would the routing distance (or other measures of spatial friction/routing cost such as time, etc.) be sufficient?

Comment: I`d like to calculate routing costs, distance, time etc.

Comment: can you add more detail as to why you can't use the method in the duplicate's answer in batch mode.

Comment: It is different because I have multiple start and end points. I have updated the question with a screenshot. Red dots are the end points (destinations), pink ones are the start points (post codes).

Comment: We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.  What precisely have you tried?

Comment: I`ve tried v.net.path which does not allow batch process, there is no option of importing a CSV file or adding a shapefile. I`d like to find a way where I can execute a batch shortest distance calculation. Can you please re-open the questions or direct me to resources that address exactly what I have raised! Thanks!